# How do I turn a table into a list of observations with various attributes in R?

Tags: r

I'm working on a project that's modeling the risk of dying in prison for indigenous and non-indigenous Australians from 1990-1995. I have a table of the data but I don't know how to convert it to a list of all the observations.

Here's my current code:

```
#DATA
years <- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995)
ind_pris <- c(2041, 2166, 2223, 2416, 2742, 2907)
ind_deaths <- c(6, 8, 2, 7, 11, 17)
ind_pop <- c(168317, 172462, 176827, 181341, 185836, 190438)
nonind_pris <- c(12264, 12855, 13336, 13450, 14302, 14501)
nonind_deaths <- c(27, 31, 34, 42, 42, 42)
nonind_pop <- c(13141817, 13326044, 13501987, 13649262, 13810095, 13995940)
all_data <- data.frame(years, ind_pris, ind_deaths, ind_pop, nonind_pris, nonind_deaths, nonind_pop)
```

How do I make it so that I have 6 lists (one for each year 1990-1995) and each list has all the observations for that year? For example in 1990, there was a total population of 13310134 (the indigenous population was 168317, plus the non-indigenous population of 13141817) and for each individual, it should record 3 attributes: 1) their indigenous status, 2) if they were in prison, and 3) if they died in prison.

Comment: So the list (or data.frame?) for 1990 should have 13310134 elements (rows?) with each element (row?) having 3 values (columns?) (I am asking bc not sure if I understand your question, also maybe data.frame would be easier to use than list of lists.. but both feasible.

Comment: Do you want `split(all_data, all_data$years)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `by`, for each year you could create two matrices filled with zeroes for Indian and non-Indian folks, with `nrow` according to their population. Then actually just fill the columns row-wise with ones with `seq_len` according to cases, assuming the deaths in your tabulated data frame refer to those in prison. Gives a `"by"` object which is very similar to a list. (Note, that I renamed your `'years'` variable using `names(all_data)[1] <- "year"` so it looks nicer.)

```
all_list <- by(all_data, all_data$year, \(x) {
  M1 <- matrix(0, x$ind_pop, 3, dimnames=list(NULL, c('ind', 'prison', 'died')))
  M1[, 'ind'] <- 1
  M1[seq_len(x$ind_pris), 'prison'] <- 1
  M1[seq_len(x$ind_deaths), 'died'] <- 1
  M2 <- matrix(0, x$nonind_pop, 3, dimnames=list(NULL, c('ind', 'prison', 'died')))
  M2[, 'ind'] <- 0
  M2[seq_len(x$nonind_pris), 'prison'] <- 1
  M2[seq_len(x$nonind_deaths), 'died'] <- 1
  rbind.data.frame(M1, M2)
})
```

### Gives

```
str(all_list)
# List of 6
# $ 1990:'data.frame':  13310134 obs. of  3 variables:
# ..$ ind   : num [1:13310134] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ prison: num [1:13310134] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ died  : num [1:13310134] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ 1991:'data.frame':  13498506 obs. of  3 variables:
# ..$ ind   : num [1:13498506] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ prison: num [1:13498506] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ died  : num [1:13498506] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 ...
# $ 1992:'data.frame':  13678814 obs. of  3 variables:
# ..$ ind   : num [1:13678814] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ prison: num [1:13678814] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ died  : num [1:13678814] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ 1993:'data.frame':  13830603 obs. of  3 variables:
# ..$ ind   : num [1:13830603] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ prison: num [1:13830603] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ died  : num [1:13830603] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
# $ 1994:'data.frame':  13995931 obs. of  3 variables:
# ..$ ind   : num [1:13995931] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ prison: num [1:13995931] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ died  : num [1:13995931] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ 1995:'data.frame':  14186378 obs. of  3 variables:
# ..$ ind   : num [1:14186378] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ prison: num [1:14186378] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# ..$ died  : num [1:14186378] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# - attr(*, "dim")= int 6
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
# ..$ all_data$year: chr [1:6] "1990" "1991" "1992" "1993" ...
# - attr(*, "call")= language by.data.frame(data = all_data, INDICES = all_data$year, FUN = function(x) {     M1 <- matrix(0, x$ind_pop, 3, dim| __truncated__ ...
#                                                                                                                          - attr(*, "class")= chr "by"

object.size(all_list)
# 1980038856 bytes
```

---

*Data:*

```
all_data <- structure(list(years = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995), 
    ind_pris = c(2041, 2166, 2223, 2416, 2742, 2907), ind_deaths = c(6, 
    8, 2, 7, 11, 17), ind_pop = c(168317, 172462, 176827, 181341, 
    185836, 190438), nonind_pris = c(12264, 12855, 13336, 13450, 
    14302, 14501), nonind_deaths = c(27, 31, 34, 42, 42, 42), 
    nonind_pop = c(13141817, 13326044, 13501987, 13649262, 13810095, 
    13995940)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error message that reads: Error in matrix(0, x$ind_pop, 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c("ind", "prison", :
non-numeric matrix extent. Any idea how to fix it? It seems like one of the matrices is being read as non-numeric, though I'm not sure why. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @M1r0W1gg1n Not sure, could you try `by(type.convert(all_data, as.is=TRUE), all_data$year, ...` ?